# In jQuery, how can I select a hidden element?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

How can I select the `<span>` where `display` is set to `none` in the below code?

```
<p id="p1">
<span id="test1" style="display:none">test1</span> 
<span id="test2" >test2</span> 
</p>
```

I can select the `<span>` whose ID is "test1" by using `$("span[id='test1']")`, but it does not work when I use `$("span[style='display:none']")`.

Is there any method to get this element at a time?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look here as well https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Answer (score 52):

You are looking for the [`:hidden`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/hidden) selector

Please note that the proper way of selecting an element by ID is simply:

```
$("#test1");
```

Doing it the way you are doing is making jQuery do unnecessary parsing and is much slower.

If you want to select `#test1` only if it is hidden, you do this:

```
$("#test1:hidden");
```

If you wanted to select all `<span>` elements that are hidden under `#p1`, you do this:

```
$("span:hidden", "#p1");
```

As noted in the comments, the opposite of this selector is the [`:visible`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible) selector:

```
$("span:visible", "#p1");
```

Would then select any visible `<span>` elements in the element `#p1`.

Comment: just to note, the opposite also exists for finding visible elements -  :visible

Comment: Fair enough. Added to answer. :)

Comment: This has apparently changed. The documentation now states: "Element assumed as hidden if it or its parents consumes no space in document. CSS visibility isn't taken into account."

Comment: `$(#test1).is(:hidden)` will return `true`. So you can add `.is(:hidden)` to your answer. This is a much cleaner solution. Check more at https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: @PaoloBergantino why `:visible` selector is not filtering `col` element. Is there any alternative way