# How to do a jquery find on intially hidden element

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a div with a class name 'form'. When the page is initially loaded this div is hidden (it's an asp.net web forms Panel control). The panel is displayed when a search button is clicked to open a search form on the page. I need to capture when the user hits enter in any of the textboxes and have it click the Search button which I've added a class named 'form-default'.

The problem I have is that my event handler isn't hooked up because because 'form' wasn't visible when the page was initially loaded and so couldn't access my textboxes. I could have them attach when the form is opened but I'm trying to get a small code snippet that can be loaded in a global file so that we can easily alot class names of 'form' to div's and 'default-form' to buttons within the div to have default buttons within the page in more than one place. I don't want developers to need to remember to hook up the calls when the UI changes. Can I use live() to hook this up or am I doing something else wrong?

```
$(".form").find(".ec-text").keydown(function(e){
if (e.which == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER){
this.closest(".form-default").click();
}
});
```

EDIT: This works fine:

```
$(".ec-text").live("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.which == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER){
        this.closest(".form-default").click();
    }
});
```

BUT I need to attach the event handler to items ONLY inside a .form div. Applying this:

```
$(".form").find(".ec-text").live("keydown", function(e){
        if (e.which == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER){
            this.closest(".form-default").click();
        }
    });
```

doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this link could help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679958/in-jquery-how-can-i-select-a-hidden-element

Comment: That will likely not help as the control is not hidden in the html/css sense.  It is not even created in the DOM by the server side code when the Visible property is set to false.

Comment: Does the form actually have a class called form on it, or is it just a form element you are trying to select? If so, leave out the dot in the .form and it should work. Also, you don't need to do $('.form').find('.ec-text'). $('.form .ec-text') would be fine.

Comment: @Stefan H. I think we actually hide the panel using jQuery to ensure the search box is rendered. I didn't think that link was much help though. Whilst you could say run this code before the search is hidden I can't 'rely' upon that being the case, with a group of developers on the team I need as elegant a solution as possible.

Comment: @Vibhu. No, it's an asp.net web forms page so the entire page is contained in a form. (Hence me adding back the asp.net tag someone removed). What I'm trying to do is have multiple sub forms (via divs) with buttons that can be assigned as default (so they fire when enter is pressed). To achieve this we've added a class named form to div tags. So $(".form") returns the element when it's visible. I just can't do the lookup on subelements when the div is initially hidden (see edits in my code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to change your live binding code so that it will bind only to items that are inside the form. (Your code didn't work because the `.find` sort of breaks the way that live handlers work.)

```
$(".form .ec-text").live("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.which == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER){
        this.closest(".form-default").click();
    }
});
```