# Hiding table rows works, but fading out does not

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I was hoping to add a fade animation when hiding table rows.

**This works:**

```
$('#myTable > tbody > tr').not("[name*=" + thing + "]").hide()
```

**This does not:**

```
$('#myTable > tbody > tr').not("[name*=" + thing + "]").fadeOut("slow")
```

I'm using the full, uncompressed (non-slim version, I believe, of jQuery):

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the element is "hidden", the jQuery selection won't work since that element isn't considered a child of the , from my understanding.

There's a few approaches mentioned in [in-jquery-how-can-i-select-a-hidden-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679958/in-jquery-how-can-i-select-a-hidden-element)*, particularly by Paolo Bergantino that would be useful here to make sure you can select the element.

For example, you may want to try something like this:

```
$("tr:hidden", "#mytable")...
```

Comment: The row is not hidden though...?  I'm using fadeout in place of hide.